# C# alternative for javascript escape function

Tags: asp.net

what is an alternative for javascript escape function in c# for e.g suppose a string:"Hi Foster's i'm missing /you" will give "Hi%20Foster%27s%20i%27m%20missing%20/you" if we use javascript escape function, but what is the alternative for c#. i have searched for it but no use.

Comment: guys, i have tested followin' but none of them replace the single quote " ' ".


Uri.EscapeDataString("some text")  
Uri.EscapeUriString("some text")  
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some text")  
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("some thext")

Answer (score 27):

You can use:

```
string encoded = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(str);
```

**Note:** You need at least ASP.NET 4.0 to run the above code.

Answer (score 7):

```
var unescapedString = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape(yourEscapedString);

var escapedString = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape(yourUnescapedString);
```

Answer (score 6):

The best solution I've seen is mentioned on this blog - [C#: Equivalent of JavaScript escape function](http://kodesharp.blogspot.com/2008/01/c-equivalent-of-javascript-escape.html) by Kaushik Chakraborti. There is more to escaping javascript than simply url-encoding or replacing spaces with entities.

Comment: +1 Yes the `escape` function is a unique beast and URLEncode simply does not behave the same.

Comment: In the answer I posted, I included the code from Reflector for this function

Comment: The `escape` function is indeed a unique beast, and this is a good reason not to use it; standard URL-encoding (`encodeURIComponent` in JavaScript) is far more often the appropriate thing to do. What's the actual use case?

Comment: @OskarKjellin I've fixed the broken link by pointing it at the new site.

Answer (score 4):

Following is the `escape` function implementation that you will find in Microsoft.JScript.dll...

```
[NotRecommended("escape"), JSFunction(JSFunctionAttributeEnum.None, JSBuiltin.Global_escape)]
public static string escape(string str)
{
    string str2 = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int length = str.Length;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length * 2);
    int num3 = -1;
    while (++num3 < length)
    {
        char ch = str[num3];
        int num2 = ch;
        if ((((0x41 > num2) || (num2 > 90)) &&
             ((0x61 > num2) || (num2 > 0x7a))) &&
             ((0x30 > num2) || (num2 > 0x39)))
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '@':
                case '*':
                case '_':
                case '+':
                case '-':
                case '.':
                case '/':
                    goto Label_0125;
            }
            builder.Append('%');
            if (num2 < 0x100)
            {
                builder.Append(str2[num2 / 0x10]);
                ch = str2[num2 % 0x10];
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append('u');
                builder.Append(str2[(num2 >> 12) % 0x10]);
                builder.Append(str2[(num2 >> 8) % 0x10]);
                builder.Append(str2[(num2 >> 4) % 0x10]);
                ch = str2[num2 % 0x10];
            }
        }
    Label_0125:
        builder.Append(ch);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Code taken from Reflector.

Answer (score 1):

> The best solution I've seen is mentioned on this blog - C#: Equivalent of JavaScript escape function by Kaushik Chakraborti. There is more to escaping javascript than simply url-encoding or replacing spaces with entities.

I noticed another solution in the comments in KodeSharp article that may be better. The comment says it is more compatible with UTF-8 and does not require the reference to JScript. Is this better?

(Dependent on System.Web.Extensions.dll)

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
JavaScriptSerializer serialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serialiser.Serialize("some \"string\"")
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but Javascript unescape did not "deserialize" it. I would have to throw it into Refelector to see what it really does.

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "Hello my friend";
myString = myString.Replace(" ", "%20");
```

This would replace all " " with "%20".

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(Obj);
```