# How to encode a URL in jQuery/JavaScript and decode in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, urlencode

How do you safely encode a URL using JavaScript such that it can be put into a GET string?

Here is what I am doing in jQuery:

```
var url = "mynewpage.aspx?id=1234";
$(location).attr('href', url);
```

And in the ASP.NET page_load, I am reading this:

```
_string _id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
```

How can I encode the id in jQuery/JavaScript and decode in ASP.NET (C#)?

Comment: This was answered pretty thoroughly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500013/c-sharp-alternative-for-javascript-escape-function

Answer (score 10):

Use `encodeURIComponent(str)` in JavaScript for encoding and use [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) to decode a URL in ASP.NET.

In JavaScript:

```
var url = "mynewpage.aspx?id="+encodeURIComponent(idvalue);
$(location).attr('href', url);
```

And in ASP.NET

```
_string _id = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've always found [this site](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/) wonderfully useful for figuring out which encoding I should be using (probably `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent`). You should be able to find what you want to use there.

I'm not as familiar with the ASP.NET side of things. [These guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-to-decode-url-param-with-c-sharp) probably already have a great answer for you.