# VB.net equivalent of escape in JS

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone have a way to convert a string to it `escape()`ed version from JS? I would be happy with a single command or a function of any kind.

Comment: I think `HttpUtility` has all this stuff..

Comment: example of an original string and the desired result?

Comment: <insert long string of characters>=!END! is the string I wish to convert into <insert long string of characters>%3D%21END%21

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# alternative for javascript escape function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500013/c-sharp-alternative-for-javascript-escape-function)

Comment: @大师 燈 Xi Huan VB.net is not the same as C# and has different methods of acquiring data, they are not the same.

Comment: *VB.net is not the same as C#*. I know. *and has different methods of acquiring data* What does that mean? *they are not the same.* I know. But where's the problem? There aren't any C#-only parts in the .Net framework. Any framework code you use with C# can also be used with VB.Net, and VB.Net is also very similar to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Buried in the linked answers](http://kodesharp.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/c-equivalent-of-javascript-escape.html),

1. Reference `Microsoft.JScript.dll` in the project reference
2. Use the `Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape` function to do the encode.

This is the same process, whether you use VB.Net, C# or nay other .Net language. They must all support `string`/`String`.

---

Alternatively, here is some code to do the same, its reflected and converted.

```
Public Shared Function Escape(str As String) As String
    Dim str2 As String = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    Dim length As Integer = str.Length
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder(length * 2)
    Dim num3 As Integer = -1

    While System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(num3) < length
        Dim ch As Char = str(num3)
        Dim num2 As Integer = ch
        If (((&H41 > num2) OrElse (num2 > 90)) AndAlso _
                ((&H61 > num2) OrElse (num2 > &H7a))) AndAlso _
                ((&H30 > num2) OrElse (num2 > &H39)) Then
            Select Case ch
                Case "@"C, "*"C, "_"C, "+"C, "-"C, "."C, "/"C
                    GoTo Label_0125
            End Select
            builder.Append("%"C)
            If num2 < &H100 Then
               builder.Append(str2(num2 / &H10))
                ch = str2(num2 Mod &H10)
            Else
                builder.Append("u"C)
                builder.Append(str2((num2 >> 12) Mod &H10))
                builder.Append(str2((num2 >> 8) Mod &H10))
                builder.Append(str2((num2 >> 4) Mod &H10))
                ch = str2(num2 Mod &H10)
            End If
        End If

        Label_0125:
        builder.Append(ch)
    End While

    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```